# Jackson calls setter but field of nested object remains null

Tags: java, json, jackson

There is a class with another static one inside. Jackson calls setters while deserializing json. But some setters doesn't work as expected.
Classes def:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "name", "imageLink", "weeklyGross", "weeklyChange" })
public class WeeklyBoxOffice {

@Embeddable
public static class WeeklyBoxOfficeID implements Serializable {

    public String country;

    public String name;

    public WeeklyBoxOfficeID() {
    }
}

public WeeklyBoxOffice() {
    this.id = new WeeklyBoxOfficeID();
}

@EmbeddedId
@JsonUnwrapped
WeeklyBoxOfficeID id;

private long weeklyGross;

private double weeklyChange;

// "weeklyGross":"$294,710"
public void setWeeklyGross(String weeklyGross) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println("setWeeklyGross called, weeklyGross = " + weeklyGross);
    this.weeklyGross = (long) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)
    .parse(weeklyGross);
}

 // "weeklyChange": "-57.1%"
public void setWeeklyChange(String weeklyChange) {
    this.weeklyChange = weeklyChange.equals("-") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(weeklyChange.replace('%', ' '));
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.id.country = country;
}

//    @JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
    System.out.println("Set name caled, name = " + name);
    this.id.name = name;
}

public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = "{\n" +
            " \"TrendingMovies\": [\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "   \"name\": \"The Dark Tower\",\n" +
            "   \"weeklyGross\": \"$461,377\",\n" +
            "   \"weeklyChange\": \"5.0\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            " ]\n" +
            "}\n";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    List<WeeklyBoxOffice> list = mapper.readValue(mapper.readTree(json).get("TrendingMovies").toString(), new TypeReference<List<WeeklyBoxOffice>>() {});

    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

> Set name caled, name = The Dark Tower
>
> setWeeklyGross called, weeklyGross = $461,377
>
> WeeklyBoxOffice{ id=WeeklyBoxOfficeID{country='null', name='null'},
>   weeklyGross=461377, weeklyChange=5.0 }

Why call of `setName` has no effect while `setWeeklyGross` and `setWeeklyChange` does and the fields of nested object remains null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `@JsonUnwrapped` and it will work fine if your remove it. If you follow your code with a debugger, you'll see that Jackson (in this order):

1. Calls `WeeklyBoxOffice` constructor that sets `WeeklyBoxOfficeID id` to an empty object (all null).
2. Calls setters for each JSON field by matching names. `setName` is called and name is set inside `WeeklyBoxOfficeID id`.
3. Handles any fields annotated as unwrapped. It can't find a `name` field in JSON as it was consumed before by `getName`. Therefore it now sets it to null.

The code will also work if you keep `@JsonUnwrapped` but remove the `setCountry` and `setName` setters which is presumably simpler. Basically use one or the other.